# Python Game Server

Tags: python, networking, python-3.x, network-programming

I'm completely lost trying to create a UDP server/client for my game in python. I'm new to the language and only have limited experience with networking. Right now, the server runs, but doesn't seem to be getting any messages from the client.

Server:

```
class GameServer:
    class GameServerUDPHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
        def handle(self):
            data = self.request[0].strip()
            socket = self.request[1]
            print("{} wrote:".format(self.client_address[0]))
            print(data)
            socket.sendto(data.upper(), self.client_address)

    def __init__(self, port):
        self.server = socketserver.UDPServer(("localhost", port), self.GameServerUDPHandler)

    def start_server(self):
        self.server.serve_forever(
```

Client:

```
import socket
import sys

class GameClient:
    def __init__(self, port, host):
        self.port = port
        self.host = host
        self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

    def register(self):
        self.socket.sendto(bytes("register\n", "utf-8"), (self.host, self.port))
        self.numberID = int(self.socket.recv(1024))
        print("Received:   {}".format(self.numberID))
```

-Main/Start of program

```
import gameserver
import gameclient

if __name__ == "__main__":
    server = gameserver.GameServer(1300)
    server.start_server()
    client = gameclient.GameClient(1300, "localhost")
    client.register()
```

NOTE: I'm most likely to multiple things wrong and may be violating several best practices in the language. I really have no clue.

Comment: I realise you've just learned a whole bunch of Python and I'm sorry to tell you, but if you want to do non-trivial networking, you'd better learn yet another framework. See [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/).

Comment: @kirelagin Thanks. I was hopping I wouldn't have to, especially since I spent several hours trying to install Twisted to no avail (Its only installed on python2 on my mac and won't work in python3 because of an error).

Comment: Oh, that's right. They have a [plan to make it work with Python 3.3](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/Plan/Python3) but I'm not sure how's their progress… I'm still afraid your best option is switching to Python 2 for now, because ntwork programming without Twisted is a pain.

Comment: @MikeG: Why don't you split the client and server into seperate processes?

Comment: @GuySirton Err... what do you mean. They're in separate classes... and I assumed that the serve_forever() thing was threaded...Sorry, I'm really new to python.

Comment: @kirelagin You wouldn't happen to have any idea when Twisted will be python3 compatible...

Comment: @MikeG: I'm not new to Python but I haven't used this library.  Why are you assuming this?  check the dosc (what I'm doing right now).  Obviously though the client and the server aren't going to be the same process, right?

Comment: @MikeG As I said, currently I'm not watching their progress, but it seems that the porting process is not really close to its end… There is also another [nice page](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/milestone/Python-3.x).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that some of these calls are blocking. In particular, the `serve_forever()` method will run forever, so you need to put that on a separate thread if you want the rest of your program to continue:

```
import threading
if __name__ == "__main__":
    server = GameServer(1300)
    server_thread = threading.Thread(target=lambda: server.start_server())
    server_thread.start()

    time.sleep(1) # Give it time to start up; not production quality code of course

    client = GameClient(1300, "localhost")
    client.register()
```

`socket.recv()` is also a blocking call but that might be okay in this case.

Comment: I was just changing it to run on a thread as this was submitted. At the start, I just assumed that it ran on a separate thread. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this library isn't asynchronous so your first call to `serve_forever` will not return and your client never gets started.  You can create a new thread to launch the server on or split your client and server into seperate processes.